# custom warning handling class init error

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings

I want to create a warning class, something like an exception.

Basically it is the following setup

```
import warnings


class customwarning(warnings):
    pass


class warning1(customwarning):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.message)
```

But when I try to run the warning I get the following error:

```
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

on this line:

```
class customwarning(warnings):
```

When searching on internet I found only

```
 warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '.*do not.*',)
 warnings.warn(Warning message')
```

But nothing about classes.
How do I create a class that works like this?

Comment: you are trying to inherit from the module, you want to inherit from the built-in `Warning` or `UserWarning`

Comment: what method should I do that I don't understand that I think...

Comment: `class customwarning(Warning):...`  is the correct inheriting from a class.  I don't understand your comment so if that wasn't what you were looking for could you rephrase your comment?

Comment: @JRichardSnape `Warning` is a built-in in both 2.7 and 3.5, no change needed to import statement (in fact `from warnings import Warning` raises an ImportError)

Comment: When I use `Warnings` I get the error above in my problem.
When I use `Warning` (the build in one) I get the error `type object 'customwarning' has no attribute 'warning1' `. So  I don't get an result jet.

Comment: @Jan-Bert That means you must be trying to do `customwarning.warning1` somewhere in your code, which in turn means this is not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Please have a look at the link and give an MCVE (i.e. show the code where you try to use your custom warning rather than saying *"when I try to run the warning "*.  e.g. I'd be expecting to see something like `warnings.warn(message, warning1, stacklevel=2)`.  Then we can probably help...

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is distinguish between what the `Warning` class and what the `warnings` class do.
The `Warning` class is the base class you want to extend in order to create your **customwarning** class while the `warnings` class is what is used to control the how your warning is dealt with once it is issued i.e whether its suppressed or shown among other things. These 2 are different things and essentially you should be using both in your code snippet.
Try:

```
import warnings


class customwarning(Warning):
    pass


class warning1(customwarning):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.message)


warnings.warn('message',warning1)
```

The final line in the code is what will render the warning to the terminal once the code has run. The 'message' string is the 1st parameter that is passed to warning1 once it is initialized.
What is represented in the dunder method `str` is what will be displayed. To change how the message is formatted from `warnings` class you can use its `.formatwarning()` method.
To find out more about `warnings` and how to use it go [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)
You could also probably do without the double inheritance and simply inherit once from `Warning` class.